# Display Values in from 3D Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, multidimensional-array

I am new to Java and I'm trying to write a code that uses a constructor, takes in employee name, Employee number and employee salary into an array and displays it using a simple display function. so far my code is failing, what am i doing wrong and how do i display it in the my display function?

below is the code so far.
`   import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

```
public class functionAssignment1 {
private int empNum;
private double empSal;
private String empname;

public functionAssignment1(int e, String d, double s){
    empNum = e;
    empname = d;
    empSal = s;
   
}

public int getEmpNum(){
    return empNum;
}

public double getSalary(){
    return empSal;
}
public String getname(){
    return empname;
}

public void display (){
    System.out.println()
}

public static void main(String[]args){
    List<functionAssignment1> employeeList= new ArrayList<functionAssignment1>();

    while (employeeList.size() < 5) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter your employee number: ");
        int e = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter your Employee name: ");
        String d= sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter your Salary: ");
        double s = sc.nextDouble();
        employeeList.add(new functionAssignment1(e,d, s));
    }
}
```

}`

Comment: Describe "failing" - are you getting any error? If so, add the error message to your question.

Comment: Btw. I don't see an array in your code (except for `args`), especially a multidimensional one.

Comment: "Write a program to accept 5 employee IDs and the corresponding names and their salaries from the user and store them in three arrays.Pass these arrays to a function display() as arguments. This display() will display the content of the arrays in the following format"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no array in your code as far I can see. A 3d array is not required for what  you want to do, as 3 parallel arrays containing the number, names, and salaries would suffice. You could use a for loop to add the input to these arrays. Your display function also should accept the arrays as arguments and print out the elements using a loop, as at the current moment `System.out.println` isn't printing anything. This should work:

```
import java.util.*;
public class functionAssignment1 {
private static int[] empNums;
private static double[] empSals;
private static String[] empnames;

public int[] getEmpNums(){
    return empNums;
}

public double[] getSalaries(){
    return empSals;
}
public String[] getnames(){
    return empnames;
}

public static void display (int[] nums, String[] names, double[] sals){
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(nums[i] + " " + names[i] + " " + sals[i]);
    }
}

public static void main(String[]args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    empNums = new int[5];
    empnames = new String[5];
    empSals = new double[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        
        System.out.println("Please enter your employee number: ");
        empNums[i] = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter your Employee name: ");
        sc.nextLine(); //so the input isn't skipped 
        empnames[i] = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter your Salary: ");
        empSals[i] = sc.nextDouble();
    }
    display(empNums, empnames, empSals);
}
}
```

I changed the 3 variables into arrays, and subsequently changed the get methods to return those arrays. The variables also had to be static, as they were being accessed by the main method, which is a static method. The same goes for the display method - speaking of which, now runs a for loop that will print the ith element of each array seperated by a space, for all 5 elements. The display method is called at the end of the main method, after all the input has been added to the arrays. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the respond! I have one more question, why are the following get methods needed?
 "public int[] getEmpNums(){
    return empNums;
}

public double[] getSalaries(){
    return empSals;
}
public String[] getnames(){
    return empnames;"

Comment: Well they're not really needed for this, but you had the get methods in your code for some reason so I figured you needed them for something else. I just changed them to use the new array variables. You'd only need them if you were trying to access the variables from another class.